# Write Custom driver for Excel to OLAP Communication in .Net

Tags: c#, excel, com, oledb, olap-cube

I am working Excel and i want to use my OLAP Cubes in Excel. So i need to write my custom Oledb Provide for communication with My OLAP Server to Excel.

I come to know that there are some interface by implementing them i can built a bridge by which i can communicate with  my olap cubes.

Can any one tell me how i can start to write my driver or any idea.

How i can communicate with external data source with Excel

Comment: Can any one tell me how can i write and register Custom Oledb Connection in c#

Answer (score 2):

An even faster approach is using the open source XMLA Connect. You can see a video of how it works here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-m64VsOvvkw. If you find it useful, you can download the latest version from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlaconnect

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write an *OLE DB for OLAP (ODBO)*-to-*Your OLAP Server* bridge.

Does your OLAP server support XMLA?

[Introduction to OLE DB for OLAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725355%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[OLE DB Programmers's Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms713643%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This can be done in c or c++, but not sure about c#.

A faster alternative might be to look at Simba's O2X Connector:

http://www.simba.com/connectors/simbao2x

Comment: I have written my Ole db Provider in c++ and it works , but can i do this in c# and Expose it as COM so that excel can use it.

Comment: You can expose a .net assembly as COM: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5001/NET-COM-Interoperability . You can also write a COM object in c or c++ .

Comment: Actually i have to show olap cubes in excel, so my oledb provider only working with single dimensional data.

Comment: My company makes another such alternative: https://www.progress.com/ole-db/custom-connector-sdk . Please take a look and let me know if you would like to learn more about it.